# Installing VirtualBox Guest Additions for guest Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I tried installing Virtual box from the VM Manager as well as Ubuntu repository.
I keep getting this

```
VirtualBox Guest Additions: To build modules for other installed kernels, run
VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup <version>
VirtualBox Guest Additions: or
VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup all
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the modules for kernel 5.4.0-37-generic.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-37-generic
**VirtualBox Guest Additions: Running kernel modules will not be replaced until 
the system is restarted**
```

I've already updated my VMware, deleted pre-existing VirtualBox Additions and tried re installing. Nothing worked.

Comment: Definitely works with unattended installs as well:
[See curtis command](https://superuser.com/questions/1544921/vboxmanage-unattended-ubuntu-live-server/1545412#1545412)

Answer (score 3):

The output you give in your question is the normal output from the process when it completes successfully. Is there a reason you believe it did not work?

You can verify the installed version of the guest additions by opening a terminal window in the virtual machine and typing `ls /opt`

I just did this successfully, note the similar output:

```
myusername@mycomputer:/media/myusername/VBox_GAs_6.1.10$sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run 
[sudo] password for myusername: 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 6.1.10 Guest Additions for Linux........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Starting.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel 
modules.  This may take a while.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: To build modules for other installed kernels, run
VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup <version>
VirtualBox Guest Additions: or
VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup all
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the modules for kernel 5.3.0-51-generic.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-51-generic
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Running kernel modules will not be replaced until 
the system is restarted
myusername@mycomputer:/media/myusername/VBox_GAs_6.1.10$ ls /opt
VBoxGuestAdditions-6.1.10
```

Comment: Huh, thankyou for the answer. Even after guest addition, ubuntu was lagging. So decided to dual boot instead.
But i installed it in legacy mode, do you know how i can convert to UEFI ?